# Title on Resume

Tags: resume, title

My title was changed to a lesser position, but I still perform the same duties.  How do I handle this on my resume and at an interview?

Comment: Did your salary change, too? Is there any sign that your management is unhappy with your performance? You are not going to handle anything if you have no idea why the change was made and you make no effort to find out.

Answer (score 4):

I would list the work under both Titles, something like:

```
Job Title 2 (Dec 2013 - Present)
Job Title 1 (Jan 2012 - Dec 2013)                    at Company XYZ
 - Work 1
 - Work 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar happen to me once where they switched a whole heap of job titles around in a restructure.  I simply left the old title in place on my CV as I felt it was more indicative of the duties I performed.  Even if someone were to check your references and ring your old employer to ask, "Was Jane employed with you as an [ old title ]?" then of course they would answer that was true.

Most organisations are looking for *skills* not job titles.  If you get as far as a referee check, they will be calling someone YOU nominated and they are already pretty sure they want to hire you.  I never had an issue from it.

Comment: I have a collection of my old, company-issued business cards for this very reason:  In case there's ever ambiguity on my employment checks.

Comment: @WesleyLong As do I.  If my duties had changes significantly, then of course I would update my CV to reflect that as fullerja has stated in their answer.